# Why doesn't this associated create call work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations, method-chaining

I've got a User model that has many Items. A Rating belongs to a User and an Item.

In the DB, I have set ratings.user_id to be not NULL.

when I am creating an Item, I would like to do this:

```
  def create
    current_user.items.create(params[:item]).ratings.create(params[:rating]
    redirect_to items_path
  end
```

However, this balks with an SQL error "user_id cannot be nil"

so I rewrote the create method as

```
  def create
    current_user.items.create(params[:item]).ratings.create(params[:rating].merge({:user_id => current_user}))
    redirect_to items_path
  end
```

which works fine.

However, I had thought that chaining the create methods off the current user's receiver would have populated the rating's user_id. Anyone know why not?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you normalize this if possible in the database. Maybe take out the user_id attribute from the ratings table and if you need it in your model get it through a join using a :through method

```
class Rating
    has_many :items
    has_one :user, :through=>:items
```

Comment: thanks Jeremy. I'll try this out. Bit of a newbie question I realise.

Comment: just wondering though: doesn't a Rating belong to an Item, not has many Items?

Comment: yes you are right, I didn't think much about that line I just intended to give you the :through example

Comment: I would do has_many :items, :through => :ratings... unless there's a reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you created and saved the Item, then made a Rating from that item, it wouldn't pass the user along to the Rating, right?  You'd just refer to it as @rating.item.user, right?

When you think about it like that, you wouldn't expect the Item created via the current_user to pass the user information along to the rating.

Make me wonder if you really need the user has_many ratings relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Because Item has many Ratings and that association does not know about the user id.  Given that association chain Item would have a user id because it belongs to a user.  And Rating would have an item id because it belongs to an item.  But the Item to Rating assocation doesn't know anything about a user unless you tell it.